# How to do the Following using JS, CSS and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[how can this picture be translated into html/css format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Dt2.jpg)

I have no idea how this can be done and i dont even know what to search in the first place. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. html allows img tags so are you just looking for that or you do want something more? Anyway, this does not look like SO is the right site for this kind of questions

Comment: Hey, please elaborate... if it's just about displaying an image via html, with css styling or whatever, there's a whole bunch of basic tutorials and websites [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)

Comment: sorry for not elaborating - what i want to do is i have a png image of that building. i want to put buttons in that specified area's like amenities, showrooms etc.. (also want it to be responsive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole picture will be set as a background image then you can locate your buttons in the position specified with CSS. You can also add some functionality to those buttons with JavaScript, like opening some window displaying an image or information about that spot on the building.

Comment: Thank You, but i got it working by responsive image mapper plugin.